# Basic Delivery Using SSH In Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-pipelines

Here's what I've got so far:

I've generated an SSH key pair inside my repo and also added the public key to my ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote host.

My remote host has root user and password login disabled for security. I put the SSH username I use to log in manually inside an environment variable called SSH_USERNAME.

Here's where I'm just not sure what to do. How should I fill out my bitbucket-pipelines.yml?

Here is the raw contents of that file... What should I add?

```
# This is a sample build configuration for JavaScript.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/14UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:          
  branches:
    master:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.          
         - sftp $FTP_USERNAME@192.241.216.482
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you should *not* add a key pair to your repo. Credentials should never be in a repo.

Defining the username as an environment variable is a good idea. You should do the same with the private key of your keypair. (But you have to Bas64-encode it – see Bb Pipelines documentation – and mark it as secure, so it is not visible in the repo settings.)

Then, before you actually want to connect, you have to make sure the private key (of course, Base64-decoded) is known to your pipeline’s SSH setup.

Basically, what you need to do in your `script` (either directly or in a shell script) is:

```
- echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- chmod go-r ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

BTW, I’d suggest also putting also the host’s IP in an env variable.

Comment: Why do you think they offer the option of generating ssh key pairs right on the site? That's what I mean when I say "add it to the repo"...Also do you have a specific doc you refer to? The docs for pipelines are so bad, it's hard to make sense of any of it...

Comment: I see. They add things from time to time, and in case I had seen that functionality already (I don’t recall, as I don’t look into the config, when the Pipelines are running), I have forgotton it. Anyways, that makes things simpler. (And adding the pwd this way is OK – I thought you meant committing it to the VCS.) So you really only have to copy the public key they show you to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target host (simply add as a new line) and fetch the host key on same screen. Then it should just work using the command above.

Comment: thank you for your detailed help, however I think I've found the solution... just use Jenkins :)

Comment: @bor83j: Did it work with the newly build in ssh-keypair feature?

Comment: @MarcelLange no I just gave up and used Jenkins instead